# xcodebuild: "Code signing is required" error after upgrading to XCode 8.1 using

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcodebuild

We used automate our builds using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -target 'Unity-iPhone' -configuration Release clean build
```

Everything worked smoothly until I upgraded to XCode 8.1.

Now building works using the XCode IDE, but I get the following output when trying to run xcodebuild:

> Check dependencies No profiles for 'com.company.project' were found: 
>   Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching
>   'com.company.project'. Warning: Multiple build commands for output
>   file
>   /Users/BuildSystem/GCLive/XCodeProject/build/Release-iphoneos/project.app/DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx
>   Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
>   /Users/BuildSystem/GCLive/XCodeProject/build/Release-iphoneos/project.app/machine.config
>   Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.1'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Tried recreating the provisioning profile, disabling "Automatically manage signing", fiddling with other things. No luck.

Any help appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: Same issue here. Can be built by using IDE, but cannot be built successfully by using command line. In Xcode 8.0
Command:
xcodebuild -project XXX.xcodeproj -scheme XXX -configuration Debug
Result:
Check dependencies
No profile matching 'XC iOS Wildcard Development' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'XC iOS Wildcard Development'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue, which was resolved by installing the command line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I guess it's already installed. I get the following: $ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: It doesn't resolve the problem.. But thanks for the attempt.