# Unable to build for iOS after Sierra Update

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have had automated builds (iOS and Android) of my Cordova application working for several months and this last weekend it looks the version of Xcode got updated on my mac where I run the builds.  My first problem was easy, just needed to accept the license agreement.  However, the second issue I have not been able to find a solution.  I am getting the same error as mentioned in this question.

No certificate matching 'iPhone Distribution: *****(******)' for team '******':  Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning.

[Unable to compile for iOS 10 after Sierra Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452033/unable-to-compile-for-ios-10-after-sierra-update)

However, I am not for sure how to try any of the sugested solutions since I am using the Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Cordova.  I have the certificate and publishing profile files encrypted in the source.  I also tried using the certificate and publish profile UUID.

Comment: Have you followed the steps by [Cordova builds with Xcode 8](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html)?

Comment: Well, I tried.  I do not have a build.json.  It appears it should go in the root folder from the corodva project.  I tried this but it was still not working.  Also, the instructions mention that you still have to go into Xcode and archive.  Before this update, my process was automated to create a release build for the app store without having to use Xcode.  I am also directly pushing to the app store from Visual Studio online.   It seems like changes need to be made for the  extension.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.cordova-extension

Comment: @Brad This worked for me after adding the build.json, but beware you have to clean / rebuild the solution afterwards. Please note that I also did this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40470103/1010492 and deleted the res/native/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig file I added a long time ago to workaround a cordova bug (not sure this is relevant though)

Comment: @GyumFox I revisited adding the build.json.  The thing that was causing that not work the first time was I still had some settings in the signing override for iOS for the VSTS Cordova Extension.  So, I have builds working.  The problem now is they are not portable to another build server, I was looking MacInCloud VSTS agents.  It seems like I have to be able to launch XCode and connect developer account, so I am using my Mac again.  I think the VSTS extension needs to be updated to handle new signing changes.  I opened an issue.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cordova-tasks/issues/58